# Can UE4 be used from multiple locations with a single license?

Tags: unreal

I want to subscribe to Unreal Engine 4 with my small game development team. But before we do, we have a question: can we also use UE4 from multiple locations at the same time? So that all of our developers have access to UE4 with just the fee of $19/month?

Comment: One question per post please. I've edited out your question about extended features since it's something better answered by reviewing the product specification information from Unreal website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The licence is per user, you need one for everyone working on it. They can then install/use it on as many PCs as they want.
There is no Git support or anything like that included. There is also nothing stopping you from using it, C++ works quite well with Git...